# how to completely uninstall VVV vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, uninstallation

how to uninstall VVV vagrant? I already removed box which comes with it, is it enought just to delete folder where I pulled VVV from git, or?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot `vagrant destroy` you can just remove the vvv folder and delete the vm via the VirtualBox interface